# Haxe implicit casts in an abstract based on haxe.ds.Either with Class as a type

Tags: haxe

I want to use the method described in this article: https://code.haxe.org/category/other/passing-different-types-to-a-function-parameter.html

It works fine as long as I provide "concrete" types, but the problem is that I want to use, for example, `Class<String>` as one of the types in `OneOf<A, B>`.

Like here:

```
import haxe.ds.Either;

abstract OneOf<A, B>(Either<A, B>) from Either<A, B> to Either<A, B> {
    @:from inline static function fromA<A, B>(a:A):OneOf<A, B> {
        return Left(a);
    }

    @:from inline static function fromB<A, B>(b:B):OneOf<A, B> {
        return Right(b);
    }

    @:to inline function toA():Null<A>
        return switch (this) {
            case Left(a): a;
            default: null;
        }

    @:to inline function toB():Null<B>
        return switch (this) {
            case Right(b): b;
            default: null;
        }
}

class Test {
    static function main() {
        Test.test(String);
    }

    static public function test(a:OneOf<Class<String>, Int>) {}
}
```

Or live example here: https://try.haxe.org/#d12d5c07

It gives compilation error:

```
Test.hx:27: characters 13-19 : Class<String> should be OneOf<Class<String>, Int>
Test.hx:27: characters 13-19 : ... For function argument 'a'
```

It probably has something to do with the fact that `Class<T>` is an abstract too.

Is there any workaround to pass not an instance of the class, but the type of this class to `OneOf`?

Answer (score 0):

In Haxe 4 you could use `EitherType` instead - so long as the options aren't two different `Class<T>`s:

```
import haxe.extern.EitherType;

class Test {
  static function test(val:EitherType<Class<String>, Int>) {
    if (val is Int) {
      trace('int: $val');
    } else {
      trace('class: $val');
    }
  }
  static function main() {
    test(4);
    test(String);
  }
}
```

> Test.hx:6: int: 4
> Test.hx:8: class: { __name__ : true }

As for your code, explicitly doing `OneOf.fromA` works, but is less convenient - perhaps this is a bug with type checking.